# Getting Error While Converting IEnumerable to System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I am using mvc4.0, enityframework 4.2.1, c#, After generating .EDMX file I tried to cast the context object to IEnumerable by the below code

```
       IEnumerable<TransactionsModel> pro = (IEnumerable<TransactionsModel>) x.ToList();
```

but I am getting the following error

```
    Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[MCLInventory.Models.Projects]' 
    to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String]'.
```

Thanks
Bhanu Prakash Inturi

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're failing on the ToList() call itself, rather than the cast.  A few suggestions...

- Do you know what kind of list you expect to come out of the `ToList()` call?  If so, have that on a separate line from the cast to `IEnumerable<TransactionsModel>`.
- I wouldn't be surprised if you need to cast x into something else first.  For that matter, what kind of object *is* x?  That's kind of pertinent to the question, and the error seems to suggest to me that what you think it is and what the program thinks it is are not the same.